# Manage application users and roles in Azure App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am really new to Azure and honestly not so familiar with Active Directory since majority of my works were relying on different users and their logins completely saved in DB.

But I have got a new requirement for a little big application and its going to work in Azure.

Its an ecommerce application, but other than being a common ecom application, its little different. Each sellers can sell their goods from their own shop page. Customers never get a feeling they are buying from a common store like Amazon.

My concern is how to handle the users and their logins and transaction. I have got confused about Azure AD because many pages says Azure AD can be use for handling the users and roles.

So does it means I dont need to store user ID and roles separately in my table and Azure AD can handle those part??

Expecting kind help because I am a beginner..

Comment: Look into Azure AD B2C, the extra effort is worth it. You get logging, security, well-known login interface, multi-factor if you want it and a lot more. I promise you, the code you write and it's iterations, will take a lot longer time than using B2C, and the endresult is way better.

Comment: Thank you friend. So we dont need to think about storing the login information or managing the logins, isnt it? But the user registration through Microsoft then?? Or are we registering the user through our portal itself and storing the data in our DB, then enabling azure authentication for that user??

Comment: All aspects of maintaining user credentials is "taken care of" by B2C, you reference them by keys from claims. If I list up a lifecycle of user credentials: Creation, forgotten password, password change, multifactor, to many sign-in attempts, changing email address, and so on... You will quickly realize that B2C is a good option. 
Other options are Identityserver or relaying on twitter/facebook/Microsoft/etc. credentials.

Comment: @RaymondA. THanks a lot.. Sorry one last question.. Wont steal your time anymore.. :)
So user registration also handles by b2c, isnt it? But that registration details I found I can customize as well. But how can I get those details stored in my DB. Not any login part. The data user entered in registration details, is that possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/).

It's service to support user credentials and authentication flows. Users can use the authentication flows to sign up, sign in, and reset their password. Azure AD B2C stores a user's sensitive authentication information, such as the user name and password. The user record is unique to each B2C tenant, and it uses either user name (email address) credentials or social identity provider credentials

you can [follow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) this on how to setup

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.. Sorry one question, is there is any limitation on number of users or do we need to pay for each user to Azure? There wont be, but a question, if there are 100k users so the above B2C will work, isnt it?

Comment: Also missed to ask one more thing, if that way (b2C), we dont need to think about storing user credentials in DB or no need to worry about managing the login as well, isnt it?

Comment: You can find the pricing details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing

Comment: @sanforall No you do not have to worry about storing user credentials. Navigate to the documentation link and you can get all the info